# How can I beat level 3-15 in Angry Birds?

Tags: angry-birds

I can't get past this level in Angry Birds. All I get is one black exploding bird and two white bomber birds:

[image: Angry Birds 3-15]

I can use the black bomber to kill the left two pigs, but after that there's such a big pile of concrete on top of the other pigs that nothing I try gets through.

Comment: I've been stuck on this level for I don't know how long -- can't believe I didn't think to use StackEx for this.

Comment: If you cant pass a level in Angry Birds then it means you havent swiped long enough.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Here's a video walkthrough of 3-11 through 3-15:

http://www.rovio.com/index.php?page=angry-birds-walkthrough-videos#3_11_15

direct link to just that video

Comment: I think it's great how you two communicate on StackExchange instead of just asking each other in person ;-)

Comment: The link is now broken, luckily the video works.

Comment: @Josh more reputation that way!

Answer (score 46):

Youtube has a bunch of these:

This is the "Official Angry Birds 3 Star Walkthrough Theme 3 Levels 11-15"

A description of what occurs in the video:

```
1. Fire black bird at gap between concrete levels 3 and 4 (one above first die).
2. Black bird explodes on top of second tall wood column. Second pig is
   destroyed.
3. Fire white bird on slightly higher trajectory, dropping egg between third
   and fourth (now second and third) pigs, destroying both.
4. Fire second white bird on lower trajectory, dropping egg between first (and
   only) remaining pig and die, destroying both.
```

Total points in example video: **56460**. ★★★

Answer (score 10):

Aim the black bird at the row just under the first dice and DON'T explode him. If you hit it right he will explode and take out 3 of the pigs. Then you are left with the two white birds to get the last pig on the end.

Answer (score 6):

Rovio has walkthroughs on YouTube:

Comment: Anyone know how they record these things?

Answer (score 1):

It's not as daunting as it looks, actually. Your exploding bird must land in amongst the concrete directly above the second pig from the left (about halfway up the structure). When it explodes it will take out the first three pigs in one hit. Remember that you can pre-detonate a bomb bird even after it's landed and gone red to time your ordnance perfectly. This leaves your MOAB birds to clear the smashed and fallen masonry from above the last pig and let the shockwave from the last one kill the porker. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can get three with the black one if you aim it at the 2nd level, then the White birds to drop bombs on the last remaining bird/s :-)